# How to truncate/remove contents from a file untill a particular size reaches

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a text file sizes around 10 KB, I need to removes lines one-by-one from the beginning of the file and needs to stop when the file reaches 5 KB . I used the following piece of code, but it is not giving me the accurate results what i want to see ( For ex : If i want to reduce it to 5 KB it stops when it reaches the 6.5 KB)

```
cacheCutOffSize = 5 * 1024; //(in KB)
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            sr.AutoFlush = true;
            while ((sr.BaseStream.Length < cacheCutOffSize) && lines.Count > 0) //*8
            {
                sr.WriteLine(strng);
                lines.RemoveAt(0);
                strng = lines[0];
            }

        }
```

Is there a better and accurate way for doing this?

Comment: StreamWriter has a buffer, this will get flushed to the output stream when you dispose of it. Why are you doing this? Are you creating a rolling log file inside a text file?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen : No my intention is not creating a rolling log file.